# How to read JSON file data and convert to OBJECT using MUELSOFT

Tags: anypoint-studio

I am new to this Muelsoft - AnyPoint Studio.
Requirement is 
Reading JSON file data and converting into OBJECT.

Comment: Hi, welcome on Stack Overflow. I think you should do a little research as to how answer questions here ;) (Google is your friend!) Your current question does not provide any details concerning the problem you are encountering. If you're looking for Mule tutorials, read the official Mule documentation and again, Google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

- Use **json to object** transformer (payload transformation) which
  transforms the json data to object as expected.
- Use the link to tranform the payload to different representation https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-examples